# javascript_include_tag doesn't see js in vendors on production environment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails version 3.1

I have file vendor/assets/javascripts/plugins/orphus.js

This script defined in application.js.coffee

```
#= require plugins/orphus
```

I call this script in template via following code:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'plugins/orphus' %>
```

It includes from development environment, but when I am deploy to production it causes error:

```
http://hostname/assets/plugins/orphus.js 404 (Not Found)
```

What causes this problem? Something tells me that root of the problem lies in production.rb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

orphus.js placed to /app/assets/javascripts/

application.js was fixed:

```
#= require orphus
```

in template fixed to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'orphus' %>
```

and run at production

```
rake assets:precompile
```

UPDATE:
here is complete orphus gem: https://github.com/tonic20/orphus_rails

Answer (score 1):

Check the asset paths to see if 'plugins/orphus' is in the paths.

```
    rails c
    y Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

if not you should add this line into 'application.rb'

```
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/plugins/orphus/"
```